# Why is Angular2 token localStorage not set when I set apiBase upon _tokenService.init()?

Tags: angular, devise, local-storage

I have a rails BE application on localhost:3000 and FE on localhost:4200. I am trying to get the token validation to be done automatically and I understand this happens through localStorage being set and retrieved during the _tokenService.validateToken() method.

The problem seems to be that once I sign in (successfully), I looked at my localStorage in my browser and found nothing saved. Hence, when I refresh the page, there is no localStorage to validate as a part of my validateToken() method and hence, the session is not maintained on the browser.

What am I missing here? Is there a mistake in the way I have initialised this command? Do I need to manually set the localStorage every time? If so, how?

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) {
         this._tokenService.init({apiBase:'http://localhost:3000'});
    }
}
```

> sign-in.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2TokenService, SignInData } from 'angular2-token';

@Component({
    selector: 'sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'sign-in.component.html'
})
export class SignInComponent {

    private _signInData: SignInData = <SignInData>{};
    private _output: any;

    constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) { }

    // Submit Data to Backend
    onSubmit() {

        this._output = null;

        this._tokenService.signIn(this._signInData).subscribe(
            res => {
                this._signInData    = <SignInData>{};
                this._output        = res;
            }, error => {
                this._signInData    = <SignInData>{};
                this._output        = error;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old one, but for any Rails users still looking for this, you need to tell your rails application to expose the necessary headers. Otherwise your client application wont be able to read them, and if it can't read it, it can't write it to your localStorage.

To do so, go to your application module located at `/config/application.rb`

This is where you should have defined your CORS policies. (If you did not set it up, you should do it before anything else, see: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

The `ressource` method of the `Rack::Cors` module allow you to pass an "expose" parameter to explicitly tell your rails application to expose specifics headers to the client. Here we need several of them:

- access-token
- client
- expiry
- token-type
- uid

I won't detail them here, but you need all of them.
As soon as those header are exposed, your client application will be able to read them, and the angular2-token library will be able to set them in your localStorage.

Code sample for `/config/application.rb`

```
module MyAwesomeRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # possibly some code and comments and then:
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options],
                 expose: ['access-token', 'client', 'expiry','token-type', 'uid'] 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you might want to limit the policy to only one or a few domains, instead of the entire world. You might also want/need to add more verbs to the `methods`array (like `:delete`, `:put`etc...) but this is another topic.

Since the library has changed, you might have a hard time figuring this out, but you can actually find this information in an issue of the github repository (that seems to correspond to this exact post) here: https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token/issues/198#issuecomment-349914649

by the way, the documentation for the new version of the gem is still valid on this point: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/config/cors

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and trial and error, the solution was in setting a proxy for specific routes. This can be done by adding the following file in the root directory of your angular application

> proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/auth": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

also include this in your

> package.json

```
{
..
..
  "scripts": {
  ...
  ...
  "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
  ...
  ...
  }
..
..
}
```

This issue fundamentally was that response headers sent were not getting allocated to my browsers localStorage through the following command

```
this._tokenService.init({apiBase:'http://localhost:3000'});
```

changed this back to

```
this._tokenService.init();
```

And instead routed all request through the /auth default routes set in the angular2-token through a proxy request to the corresponding rails routes.